# How to link a hmtl page to another html in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I have page 1 saved in html by Rmarkdown and I want to put a link to the second page of html made by Rmarkdown. How to do this in Rmarkdown?

page1.rmd:

````
---
title: "page1"
author: "ww"
date: "25 lutego 2017"
output: html_document
---


###working directory
My rmarkdown files are saved here: `r getwd()`

The list of saved files in working directory:
```{r echo=T}
as.list(list.files(getwd()))
```


##checking the link to the next page
[LINK to another html file]("C:/R/rmarkdown/page2.html")
````

page2.rmd:

```
---
title: "page2"
author: "ww"
date: "25 lutego 2017"
output: html_document
---
#tytuĹ‚
this is the second document

it works!!! :)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work :(
The files are in the same directory C/R/rmarkdown

Comment: Use relative paths and link like this: `[LINK to another html file](page2.html)`

Comment: oh, it works, thx, bro!

Comment: You have written absolute path: `"C:/R/rmarkdown/page2.html"`